# Delphi - Already opened tab in pagecontrol

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe

This is about PageControl with dynamic tabs. I have 5 buttons (Button1, Button2, Button3, Button4, Button5).

**I want the following:**

1. Each click on a button will open a new `TtabSheet`.
2. When clicked on the same button the 'Ttabsheet' already opened, should be shown again.

How to do this?

Comment: So when you click on a button you want the page to be displayed?

Comment: and can you explain the second part?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your question to show [the code you have so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include at least an outline (but preferably a [mcve]) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Comment: I have success to add page on every button, but when i click the same button again there is add a new page. i want if i click the same button that show the recent opened Tab page.

Comment: ok so when you press the button a page is added. and when you press the same button you expect it to show the page already added and not add a new page. is that what are you asking for?

Comment: @Nasreddine Abdelillah Galfout : That's right, that's what I mean

Comment: You still need to show us what code you are working on (or a simplified version). It makes it much easier for us to help you.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I don't know why you really want to have five buttons doing the job of creating the tabs and then selecting them, but this is one of the approaches you can try

```
uses System.Generics.Collections;

...

var
Newtabsheet: Ttabsheet;
Tabs: TList<Ttabsheet>;
Index: array[1..5] of Integer;
Ex: array [1..5] of Boolean;

implementation
```

Put this on the `Formcreate` handler

```
procedure TForm6.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
Tabs := Tlist<Ttabsheet>.create;
for I=1 to 5 do ex[I]:=false;
end;
```

And this on each `OnClickButton` event handler

```
procedure TForm6.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
if not(Ex[1])then
  begin
  Newtabsheet := Ttabsheet.Create(PageControl1);
  NewTabSheet.PageControl := PageControl1;
  Newtabsheet.Caption := 'Tab 1';
  Index[1] := Tabs.Count;
  Tabs.Add(Newtabsheet);
  Ex[1] := true;
  end
else
  begin
  Pagecontrol1.ActivePage := Tabs.List[Index[1]];
  end;
end;

procedure TForm6.FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
begin
Tabs.Free;
end;
```

Remember changing the numbers.

It is tested on RAD studio Seattle.

**Note:** based on david comments I have edited my answer. and for further explanation please see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43820424/ownership-principals-when-using-tpagecontrol)

Comment: Yes It can run well, but when I delete the tab it can not re-open the same tab. what should I do?

Comment: when you delete the tab  do 'ex(number of the tab) :=false;' and it should do the trick.

Comment: just one thing when you delete the tab you are deleting it from the 'tabs' list right?

Comment: yeah you are right, I just use PageControl1.ActivePage.free with statement list of the tabs active.

Comment: Where should I put the code? Because after I put it on the delete tab that is not working

Comment: This code is very messy. At the very least it should be using an array rather than 5 variables. Anyway, it's way easier to throw away all of the code and use the TabVisible property of tab sheets.

Comment: @NasreddineAbdelillahGalfout I think `TabVisible` property will work as needed as Davids say.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I improved the formatting, However I don't see how `TabVisible` would make it easier. With the requirement set by the OP _the same button creating the tab should select it when clicked again_ , you would still need to store a reference to the `Ttabsheet`s created dynamically  and you will also have to create them and delete them when needed (also required by OP from his first comment ), I really want to see how could I have done this using `TabVisible`

Answer (score 0):

Just define variable like `fPreviousTabIndex` inside your form class, where you store the last state (`ActivePageIndex` property of the TPageControl).

The next part is already simple...

```
procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
const
  DESIRED_PAGE_INDEX = 2;
begin
  if PageControl.ActivePageIndex = DESIRED_PAGE_INDEX then
    PageControl.ActivePageIndex := fPreviousTabIndex
  else
  begin
    fPreviousPageIndex := PageControl.ActivePageIndex;
    PageControl.ActivePageIndex := DESIRED_PAGE_INDEX;
  end;
end;
```

Of course you need to initialize the `fPreviousTabIndex` during creation of the form.

Comment: the problem is that the same button creating the tab should select it when clicked again.